# Message queue: get messages since a certain time

Tags: python, rabbitmq, message-queue

I am implementing a specification for a web service. I have a function called `getMessages(time)` where you specify a time, and you get any messages since that time returned to you. I would like to back this function up using a message queue, something like RabbitMQ, but I am not sure if you can do such a thing as querying the queue for messages older than a certain date, or even if it is a good idea to do it this way (I am aware of the synchronisation issues, particularly if the queue is on a different server to the web service but that is what the spec is asking for)

Comment: I doubt that you can do that with RabbitMQ, as it's a dumb queue to some extent. You could, however, use Rabbit to push messages to a database or just a dict in a python process that you could push and pop queue style, depending how big/stable your system needs to be.

Comment: thanks @nathancahill, I thought it would be a long shot, I think I might just end up using a db and running a query to filter the results.

Comment: Is the point of this to queue messages, or to retrieve logs of messages?  Generally speaking, having a message queue implies that messages dump in one side and are taken out the other, so putting in a date component is irrelevant; in that case, what you want is not a message queue but a database.

Comment: Agreed, I was trying to avoid a database, as it seemed a bit heavyweight just for storing messages for later retrieval, however I ended up using MongoDb as it is a lot lighter (no explicit schemas etc) and you can easily filter a collection with a greater than against a dat